# Crystal report Invoking Error in Visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports, vb.net-2010

I am developing WinForms Application using vb.net in visual studio 2012. And I have downloaded SAP crystal report for Visual Studio 2012 to take the reports from my application.
So i downloaded the following two files.

1) (SAP Crystal Reports, developer version for Microsoft Visual Studio SP5 - MSI 32bit) CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_5.msi  from http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-35074

2) Crystal report Installer file CRforVS_13_0_5.exe

After Installing the first file I got references in visual studio 2012 as :
[image]

I dont Know which reference should be included to create crystal reports in VS.
And I installed Second file also. It Installed Successfully and i found the crystalreportviewer in Reporting tab of toolbox. I Selected that tool and i choose create new report. That time I am getting the error like :
Error Invoking 'Create a new Crystal report...' Details: Can't resolve strongly report class at design time.
What does this mean?
what is the solution to this ? Sorry I am new to crystal reports. Thanku....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall the CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_5.msi and CRforVS_13_0_5.exe packages, then install only CRforVS_13_0_5.exe.

Inside the exe there are the designer for Visual Studio and the runtimes files (the same contained in CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_5.msi)

There is no need to include libraries reference when generating a new report, but if you use the CrystalReportViewer you'll have to include:

- CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
- CrystalDecisions.ReportSource
- CrystalDecisions.Shared
- CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms

Answer (score 0):

To create a new Crystal Report, in your VS solution explorer, right-click on your solution and choose "Add". In the resulting window, click on "Reporting" in the Installed Templates" and choose "Crystal Report". Give the report a name and click "Add". The new report will be added to your solution and the report wizard will start.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Ok I created report. Next I should select the report in crystal report viewer right.. ? While selecting it I am getting an error saying : An error occured while adding a strongly typed report document. The report may be corrupt or Invalid.

Comment: I would suggest to uninstall the CR runtimes that you have installed and then ONLY install the exe file. Do that and then try adding a CrystalReportViewer to your solution. When adding a Viewer, there should also be a CrystalReportSource added with it. In the ReprtSource is where you specify the report.